# Get the contents of a word document, replace a string and send the data to download as a word document using codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function sample($username = false) {
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $filename = base_url() . "resources/Sample-Letter.doc";

    $contents = file_get_contents($filename); // Read the file's contents

    if ($username) {
        $contents = str_replace('string_to_find', $username, $contents);
        // replace the string
    }
    $name = 'Sample-Letter.doc';

    force_download($name, $contents);
}
```

After this, file is getting downloaded with corrupted data and some special characters like �� and so on exactly like what if echo the $contents after file_get_contents.
If no username is passed to sample(), download works fine with the actual content.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

$contents = str_replace('$[Client name]', $username, $contents);

Comment: [Client name] - this is just a string inside the word document

Comment: Tried. Downloading the file but with no changes

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as its working for me

```
$contents = str_replace('[Client name]', $username, $contents);    
$contents = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $contents);//it will remove all special characters from a string
```

then try this

```
'/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s' instead of '/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/'
```

Comment: This has just removed the special characters ��. But there are some unncessary characters and it has changed the allignments, font size, spaces also in the data. It has downloaded the file with one page in the above manner

Comment: Still the same issue. Btw, it is not the issue with preg_replace I guess but with the way im downloading. Word document is changed totally after a string is replaced within it. If I don't change the data it downloads.